# Curries arrow function in JS

Tags: javascript, express, nodes

Please explain this function in simple format(without arrow use) and I am confused in promise.resolve "foo" is argument or a callback function

```
module.exports= foo =>(req,res,next)=>
Promise.resolve(foo(req,res,next)).catch(err=>next(err))
```

Comment: `Promise.resolve` is only necessary when `foo` is not an `async function` that always returns a promise

Comment: This function wraps another function calls in a promise and catches exceptions.

Comment: @Bergi I only described the code and translated arrow functions to classic functions with same behavior. I don't know how and where the function is called. I can't tell if it's necessary or not. Maybe there is some kind of request handler manager involved that uses the return value.

Comment: @jabaa Oh right I missed "*simple format(without arrow use)*"

Comment: @jabaa when i wrote function in your given format it shows maximum call stack size exceed. Can you please help!!    module.exports = function foo(req,res,next) { return Promise.resolve(foo(req,res,next)).catch(function (err) { return next(err); }); }

Comment: It's `module.exports = function (foo) { return function (req,res,next) { return Promise.resolve(foo(req,res,next)).catch(function (err) { return next(err); }); }; }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you already know what Promise.resolve does, so I'll just explain the foo part.

Ah heck, why not just explain everything.

`Promise.resolve` returns a promise that immediately resolves with the value given.
For instance, if you did:

```js
Promise.resolve(2 * 2)
.then(function(value) {
    console.log('Received value', value);
});
```

you'd instantly see a console message saying `Received value 4`

```js
foo(req, res, next)
```

`foo` is a function that will do something using the three callback functions: `req`, `res`, and `next`

So what this does:

```js
Promise.resolve(foo(req, res, next)).catch(err => next(err))
```

rewritten without arrow functions:

```js
Promise.resolve(foo(req, res, next))
.catch(function(err) {
    return next(err)
});
```

is that it takes the 'result' of this function call

```js
foo(req, res, next)
```

and sends it to the `Promise.resolve` function, which will return a Promise that resolves to that said 'result'.

The `.catch` method will catch any errors that occurred in the `foo` function call and pass it to the `next` callback to handle it.

Hope this clarifies any doubts you have.

Comment: Perhaps worthwhile explaining that the return value of a route such as `foo(req, res, next)` is usually meaningless.  `foo` would be complete when either `res.xxx()` was called to send a response or `next()` or `next(err)` was called.